# Are non-parametric statistical methods useful or not frequently used?

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data

Whenever I see some biostatistics paper, they use a kruskal-wallis rank sum test once not even twice, and I'm wondering whether nonparametric statistics are actually useful or just something that's rarely used since it's to compare ordinal data that were developed from some subjective rating system of clustering algorithm with K-Means. Are the conclusions from these tests on ordinal data even useful? I don't even think ordinal data exists in nature.

Comment: Why do you think nonparametric statistics was developed to compare ordinal data developed from subjective rating systems and clustering with K-means?

Comment: Because they're called the "rank-sum" tests.

Comment: You have an... extremely limited... view of what nonparametric statistics is; there is far more to nonparametric statistics than the Kruskal-Wallis test... the link in the next comment might convince you that there's far more to the topic than just rank-sum tests.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS810US810&q=Nonparametric+Statistical+Methods&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAH2PvQ6CMBSF08HEGH0DSaqTWwuIwEPo4uZioCVSgbaUyt_j-Dg8kpOJKUYHHb9895yTO12uZ6hAeCedDmeOxQWXkYqKRCtGYKUjzSrNSAVjIbLThnGtBL0RzQSHWsBf5wP4aB1B-WnbDWCOLsi2XUVCWoQGnZj3Xh_QASxeNvZLIkvujkw85-qdsXynmz6QvDHIcVznpN0a7GjjZkWrzC5xu7q1H8A6_PvtPll9--PooxzuE50KWj0BeQN9GC0BAAA&ved=2ahUKEwieu4jaw_foAhVqHzQIHX9aBckQxA0wJnoECAgQBA&biw=1920&bih=1057&safe=active&ssui=on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that non-parametric statistics is still very relevant, but it has transitioned quite a bit from what was developed before the computer age.

Back when most calculations were done by hand, or with a hand-held calculator, several methods were developed that were relatively simple to do, could be looked up in a table, and had reasonable properties (good approximation to the ideal under certain circumstances).  Some intro stats books still introduce a few of these in an optional chapter at the end to use for "small" sample sizes.  So these are the tools that are often thought of by people who have not taken the deep dive into the field.

I see 2 main reasons why these simple approximations are not used as much any more (I still see them used, just not as frequently).

The first is big data; these days it is much easier to collect larger datasets, so the Central Limit Theorem comes into play much more often and we can just focus on means and use normal theory methods even if we don't believe that the original population (or other data generating procedure) is normally distributed.

The second is computing power.  The basic tests are actually special cases of permutation tests, but they use a test-statistic that is non-intuitive, hard to understand, and even harder to explain.  Since they are permutation tests, with modern computers we can do our own permutation tests easily and quickly.  I expect that I could do a basic permutation test comparing the mean of 2 groups in less time than it would take me to find a copy of the table used for the Mann-Whitney test.  And I can do my permutation test comparing the mean, median, or other statistic of interest instead of the non-intuitive MW test statistic.

Others more expert than me in this area may have additional ideas of how and why things have changed.

There are still many situations that benefit from non-parametric statistics, but most are more advanced, so don't end up detailed in the intro course text books.  Some you really need to understand what you are doing; others have been automated enough that you may be using them without realizing that you are doing non-parametric statistics (and some things probably fall in both categories, so people are using them without understanding them and possibly misusing them).